# jquery-InputMast overriding existing events on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

In below code I have attached onChange() event on id "phone_world" and also applying input mask on it.
Input mast is working fine but removing existing event and hello function is not getting called.

```
<div class="demo">
<input type="text" id="phone_world" onChange = "hello()" value="" size="25">
<label for="phone_world" id="descr_world">Страны мира</label>
```

```
<script>
  var listCountries = $.masksSort($.masksLoad("https://cdn.rawgit.com/andr-04/inputmask-multi/master/data/phone-codes.json"), ['#'], /[0-9]|#/, "mask");

  var maskOpts = {
    inputmask: {
      definitions: {
    '#': {
      validator: "[0-9]",
      cardinality: 1
    }
  },
  showMaskOnHover: false,
  autoUnmask: true,
  clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
},
  match: /[0-9]/,
  replace: '#',
  listKey: "mask"
};
var maskChangeWorld = function(maskObj, determined) {
if (determined) {
    var hint = maskObj.name_ru;
    if (maskObj.desc_ru && maskObj.desc_ru != "") {
    hint += " (" + maskObj.desc_ru + ")";
  }
  $("#descr_world").html(hint);
 } else {
    $("#descr_world").html("Страны мира");
  }
}
  $('#phone_world').inputmasks($.extend(true, {}, maskOpts, {
     list: listCountries,
     onMaskChange: maskChangeWorld
 }));
  function hello(){
   alert('hi');
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you add a working snippet of the same, with all the js dependency. May be you need to add some callback function of inputmask such as `onKeyDown` or `onKeyValidation`. Check the [documentation here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#jqueryinputmask-3x).

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/kp183q11/light/
Check this fiddle link.
Here we just need to add onClick = "Hello" on id="phone_world" and Hello function.

Comment: @aManHasNoName Can we add two functions at a time inside inputMask options ?
I am trying to add onKeyValidation() but it is only executing onMaskChange()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jQuery input mask multi's [docs](https://github.com/andr-04/inputmask-multi), the `keydown, keypress, paste, input, dragdrop, drop & blur` events are interrupted, however it seems like the `change` event is interrupted as well (and not documented). What you can do is bind the `focus` and `blur` events to check for the change (with some help of the `data()` function to save the changes and compare them).

Here is a sample of the code:

```
$('#phone_world')
    .on('focus', function() {
        $(this).data('original-val', $(this).val())
    })
    .on('blur', function() {
        if ($(this).data('original-val') != $(this).val()) {    
            alert('value changed')
        } else {
            alert("value wasn't changed")
        }
    });
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/5a6xo8kc/

Comment: @Kalashir, you are welcome :) a voteup will be appreciated as well. Thanks!